# Audio not playing in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I've been trying to play an external sound file in Flash and failing miserably.

The code couldn't be simpler:

```
var s:Sound = new Sound();  
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(MovieClip(root).videoLink);  
var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(3000, true);   
s.load(req, context);  
var my_channel:SoundChannel;  
my_channel = s.play(0);
```

videoLink is a string containing a valid link to a WAV file on the same server.

The problem with this code is, I can only run it while it's on a live server (the link is obtained from a MySQL database via XML), so I can't tell if any error when it's being run. Then again, I can't see how the above code can lead to any problems.

I've spent more than 2 hours trying different solutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Andrey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sound file should be a mp3 , not a wav. try the same code with an mp3 version and it should play.

Check this article, for info on how to play wav files with as3
http://richapps.de/?p=97

Comment: YES. Obviously it had to be something simple like that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nice little gotcha about mp3 is, if you make any money off your project and it uses an mp3, you have to pay royalties to the people who hold the mp3 patents...just a warning.